# variable nested templates in cheetah

Tags: include, cheetah

i have a base template that calls a nested template based on a variable passed in, eg.

```
page = 6
```

and what i want is to call some html as follows:

```
...
<div>
    #include "templates/_page${page}.tmpl"
</div>
...
```

what is the correct syntax for this? thanks.

PS. i have managed this:

```
#if $page.id == 6
    #include "templates/_page6.tmpl"
#end if
```

but any improvement welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, all it took was a few nights sleep but i got a solution:

```
#include "templates/_page"+str($page)+".tmpl"
```

i slightly expanded the code and it works. HTH